# ParseObjects differences

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm developing an android application using Parse Mobile Backend as a Service
and I have 2 questions:

What is the difference between signUpInBackground and signUp Parse Objects ?
also between logInInBackground and logIn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also `signUpInBackground` has a SignUpCallback as an argument with a callback method `public void done(ParseException e)`. So in case of an exception it will be delivered to a client as an argument of callback method where you can handle this situation. If you use `signUp` method you must wrap this call with try-catch block with ParseException.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the "inBackground"- methods spawn a new thread and performs the sign up asynchronously, while the other methods will block the main thread while sign up is in progress.